# How to set default opening page to Area's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the project structure (see below). When I launch the project I get this error (see below). Could you tell me the change I have to do, I'd like when I start the project go to MyAreas1\Home

Thanks,

**Error message :**
*The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:*

```
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must set specified routing in `Global.asax` file

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "MyArea1/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

So what you need is to edit your default route.

Comment: When I do that, I have this error : "HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found"

Comment: I have a mistake. Instead of "MyArea1" I wrote "MyAreas1". Have a try with new edit.

Comment: Ooops didn't see myself, changed, same error: "HTTP Error 404.20 - Not Found No default document."

Answer (score 1):

Try right click on the **project >> properties>> Web>>** 
now check Specific Page option and type the **controllerName/ActionName**

Answer (score 0):

routes.MapRoute(
                "Area",
                "",
                new { area = "AreaName", controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" }
            );